# Troubleshooting port forwarding

Tags: iptables, routing, port-forwarding, openwrt

I'm trying to run a web server from my home network, but I have some difficulty reaching my server from the WAN.

If you have an idea where the problem could lie, or need more information, please let me know.

**The setup:**

[image: setup]

*ISP router*

I've enabled port forwarding on the ISP's router in the web interface. I however have no control over the firewall settings other than enable/disable. I seems only logical the the firewall respects the port forwarding...

I can confirm that the port is open on the WAN, because I used nmap to scan my open ports.

I am also positive that I forwarded the port to the right IP address, because the ISP's router only has one client; the openWRT router.

*OpenWRT Router*

I've enabled the port forwarding the the Luci web interface:

[image: OpenWRT01]

[image: OpenWRT02]

*Web Server*

For testing purposes the web server does not have any Iptables set, and it's defaults are set to ACCEPT.

However I am unable to reach the web server from my external IP.

[image: Browser]

Comment: In OpenWRT create a VLAN for WebServer interface and set it as DMZ just to be sure.. if that config works than you can leave the VLAN and configure only proper ports... The following will guide you thru the process : http://blog.christophersmart.com/2015/01/17/creating-a-dmz-in-openwrt/

Comment: try using a port other than `80` or `443` as most ISPs block those ports on the inbound

Comment: Does the webserver have internet access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Tools:

1. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) (or any other packet network protocol analyzer) on your *Web server* machine might be useful in troubleshooting:

   - On `Capture Options`:
     [image: Wireshark config]
   - Select your LAN network interface (`enp0s3` on screen-shoot).
   - Enter Capture Filter: `host a.b.c.d and port 80` (replace `a.b.c.d` with your *Web server* IP address).
   - `Start` capture.
   - *Example:* Wireshark capture for `www.superuser.com` Web browser connection:
     [image: Wireshark HTTP packets dump]
     **Notice the HTTP packets!**
2. [Telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) is basic tool useful to determine if a port is opened/listening.

   - Enter in command-line `telnet a.b.c.d 80` where `a.b.c.d` is your *Web server* IP address.
   - *Example:* `telnet 104.16.127.192 80` connection output:
     `Trying 04.16.127.192...
     Connected to 104.16.127.192.
     Escape character is '^]'.
     Connection closed by foreign host.`
   - *Example:* Wireshark capture of above telnet command:
     [image: Wireshark telnet packets dump]

---

### Test procedure:

*Start Wireshark capture on Web server IP address and port on your Web server machine.*

1. *Web server* LAN network.

   - Connect to your *Web server* LAN IP address from **any other device (not the *Web server* machine)** from your LAN network with Web browser or telnet.
   - You should capture some HTTP packets with Wireshark and/or connect to your Web server from other machine Web browser.
   - If everything works your *Web server* is configured correctly and you can go further...

*Restart Wireshark capture eventually...*

*Steps 2 and 3 are interchangeable.*

2. *OpenWRT router* WAN network.

   - Connect to your *Web server* from the *OpenWRT router* WAN network (Web browser or telnet on machine connected to the *OpenWRT router* WAN network).
   - If everything works your *OpenWRT router* is configured correctly and you can go further...

*Restart Wireshark capture eventually...*

3. *ISP modem/router* LAN network.

   - Connect your *Web server* machine directly to the *ISP modem/router* LAN port.
   - Eventually adjust *ISP modem/router* and *Web server* network configurations.
   - Try to access your *Web server* from internet (on [*ISP modem/router* WAN IP address](http://whatismyipaddress.com/)).
   - If everything works your *ISP modem/router* is configured correctly and you can go further...

*This way you can locate source of your problems (Web server, ISP modem/router or OpenWRT router configuration)...*

Comment: Thanks for helping me pin-point the problem. I've configured the OpenWRT router to be a bridge instead of having two routers.